# Restore fragment view on pressing the back button

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack

I have an activity where I place fragment A. Then on clicking the fragment A, I replace the fragment A with fragment B. Now when I press the back button it shows fragment A. But the whole view is recreated. I am calling services in Fragment A so those services get called again. I want Fragment A to be restored without creating the view again. If service call is in process on Fragment A and I go to fragment B and come back, then it should resume the service call.

Please suggest me how to do this.

Comment: can you post your service code?

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Set your services up in a retained fragment.

[This blog](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) provides a good overview on this topic. It talks about retained fragments in relation to AsycTasks, but the principle is the same.

**Option 2:**

In your [Fragment lifecycle methods](http://developer.android.com/images/fragment_lifecycle.png), put a check in to ensure the services are only started once.

Consider the following psudo-code:

```
Fragment A {

    onCreate() {
        boolean servicesStarted = false;
        ...
    }

    onResume() {
        if (servicesStarted == false) {
            startTheServices();
            servicesStarted = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not using Async Tasks. I am using Robospice. So all the threading things are automatically handled. I just need to persist the state of fragment when I press back button.

Comment: I understand you are not using AsyncTasks, but the principle is the same. Do all your Robospice service stuff in a retained fragment. Your Fragment A can get the info it needs to display from this retained fragment each time it's created. So Fragment A is just your visual User Interface, the retained fragment actually does all the service work.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I want that if I fragment A with all the data and then I go to fragment B and come back, it should show the fragment A as I left it without calling the onCreateView or the services again.

Comment: onCreateView will always be called. It's part of the fragment activity lifecycle. Have a look at my updated answer.